# Pie de pagina siempre abajo

Tags: html

Buenas estoy aprendiendo html y css y al agregar los artículos el texto se me pasa al lado derecho como podéis ver la foto. Lo que quiero es que el pie de pagina este siempre debajo. Gracias de antemano y perdón por la pregunta tan estúpida.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]